# How to find the orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oia1o.png)

Consider the quadratic space  (R^3,ϕ) where ϕ is the symmetric bilinear form given in the standard basis (e1, e2, e3) of R^3
by the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & -4 \\ 3 & -1 & 7 \\ -4 & 7 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

1. Show that ϕ is a perfect pairing.
2. Find the orthogonal L of the plane generated by e1 and e2.
3. Find the orthogonal P of the line generated by e3.

1 is clear for me, but im strugling with 2 and 3.
I have read something about Gram-Schmidt methode ? But can i use this in this case?
and maybe a stupid question, but for 3 couldnt we take e1 or e2 ? since the standard basis vectors are orthogonal to each other ?
I would be very thankful for a tip.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting for mathematical experiences. See  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that *orthogonal* in this context means orthogonal *relative to $\phi$*. Thus, the line $L$ that answers question $2$ is the set of vectors $x$ that satisfy the equations
$$
e_1^T Ax = 0, \quad e_2^T Ax = 0.
$$
Equivalently, it is the solution space to the equation
$$
\pmatrix{1&3&-4\\3&-1&7} x = 0.
$$
Similarly, the plane $P$ that answers question $3$ is the set of vectors $x$ that satisfy the equation $e_3^TAx = 0$.

Comment: omg it was that simple.. i was thinking( and crying in the inside) for like 4 hours.. Thank you very much! You saved my day !!